# I need to execute with ansible following command: FOR /f "skip=7 delims=" %%a IN (' DIR D:\backups\auto\ /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q "D:\backups\auto\%%a"

Tags: ansible

I need execute with ansible following command:

```
FOR /f "skip=7 delims=" %%a IN (' DIR D:\backups\auto\ /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q "D:\backups\auto\%%a"
```

---

tried this:

```
- name: clear old backups
  win_command: 
    FOR /f "skip=7 delims=" %%a IN (' DIR D:\backups\auto\ /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q "D:\backups\auto\%%a"
```

Comment: Hi Roman, welcome to SO. You specified what you tried, but not what the **error message** was that brought you to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section otherwise no one can reproduce your error in order to help you. Also, in the future, please use the formatting markup, **especially** for ansible questions which are whitespace sensitive. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While the [`win_command:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_command_module.html) documentation is silent about the fact, it appears based on reading the [`win_shell:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/win_shell_module.html) documentation that PowerShell.exe is the default, not CMD.exe

In the `win_shell:` docs it says you can explicitly opt to use CMD.exe instead of powershell by specifying `executable: cmd.exe` in the `args:` for the task:

```
- name: clear old backups
  win_shell: 
    FOR /f "skip=7 delims=" %%a IN (' DIR D:\backups\auto\ /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q "D:\backups\auto\%%a"
  args:
    executable: cmd.exe
```

For the same reason that `win_command:` does not permit shell operators, one must use `win_shell:` to have access to the shell built-ins, such as `FOR` and `IF` expressions

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I tried above and following error occurred:

fatal: [my_server]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": 

"FOR /f \"skip=7 delims=\" %%a IN ('DIR D:\\backups\\auto\\ /o-d /b') DO RD /S /Q \"D:\\backups\\auto\\%%a\""

"msg": "Exception calling \"SearchPath\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"Could not find file 'FOR.exe'.\"", "rc": 2}

Comment: Ok, then `win_command:` _only_ works with things that end in `.com` or `.exe`, so you'll be required to use `win_shell:` for that operation, but still with the `executable:` (or, of course, switch to the much more sane PowerShell syntax)